# .htaccess how can I allow the access to a directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess

How can I only allow the access to a directory in a web server if the user cames from a url in my domain. example: if the user is in the url mydomain.com/folder can access to mydomain.com/secretfolder
But if the user is in mydomain.com can´t access to mydomain.com/secretfolder not even if he write the url in the browser.
I d like to put the rules in a htaccess in the apache server.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if what you asking for is possible in an .htaccess, I suggest you to use an .htpasswd in the secretfolder directory, or maybe an IP authentification if you dont have a lot of users to manage. Else, I would have used some javascript but it's probably not the best way cause it's easily fakeable :

```
function goToSecretFolder()
{
    if(window.location.href == "mydomain.com/folder")
    {
        window.location.replace("mydomain.com/secretfolder"); 
    }
    else
    {
        //redirect to another page/error403
    }
}
```